# React Native start not possible : Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to launch the debug server with a simple

```
react-native start
```

But it still gives me this error:

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
```

Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
It worked yesterday and I didn't change anything. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finnaly got this working with:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/
```